# Метод sort() в Js - не верно кажется сортирует

Tags: javascript

Подскаите пожалуйста, почему в данном коде идет не верная сортировка?

```
let w = [1, 23, 1, 22, 21, 9]
w.sort()
console.log(w)
//> Array [1, 1, 21, 22, 23, 9]
```

проверено на https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Первый пример в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Элементы сортируются путём преобразования их в строки.

Comment: Так происходит, потому что он сравнивает посимвольно. Sort (функция высшего порядка) в первой итерация (1, 1, 2,2, 3, 4) и так далее. Что бы сортировать корректно нужно передать калбек. (a, b) => a - b (по возрастанию) b - a (по убыванию ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документации написано

> Порядок сортировки по умолчанию — восходящий, основанный **на преобразовании элементов в строки** и последующем сравнении их последовательностей значений кодовых единиц UTF-16.

Т.е. по сути по умлочанию сортируются строки. В этом проблема.

Поэтому лучше всегда писать компаратор для сравнения.